# how to test which method takes how much time to execute in .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How can I test which method takes how much time to execute in a .Net web application?

In the log in page I have lots of methods and I want to know which method takes a long time to execute.

What is the best tool to find out the execution time of each method?

Comment: You can use tracing but do it only on development version to check methods time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a profiler tool like [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). Such tools will usually give you a pretty good idea of the execution times.

Since the login probably executes database queries, you may want to check how long the queries take on their own. With an OR mapper that's usually the bottleneck anyway. When using NHibernate [NHibernate Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) is basically a must have.

Without tools, I'd recommend to implement a `LoggingStopwatch` which utilizes your logging class and a `StopWatch` internally.

Simplified example:

```
public class LoggingStopwatch : IDisposable
{
    public LoggingStopwatch(ILogger logger, LogLevel level, string message)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
        this.message = message;
        this.stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        this.Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // compare this.logLevel with the one set in this.logger
        // and return if no output will be generated
        // start stopwatch, log entry
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // stop stopwatch, log entry
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Stop();
    }
}
```

(**Simplified** to show the actual idea. I mean it! That's not how you actually implement the `Disposable` pattern for example.)

Since it implements `IDisposable`, you can use it like this:

```
using (new LoggingStopwatch(this.logger, LogLevel.Trace, "initializing backend session or whatever")
{
    // business logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use tracing to check the diagnostic information about a single request for an ASP.NET page

Although there are 2 types of tracing

1. Application Level
2. Page Level

**Application Level**

To enable Tracing in the application level just add the below Element `System.web` element.

```
<trace pageOutput="true"
enabled="true"
localOnly="false" //Making this attribute true ,will only show the tracing information in the local(server) !Recommended
traceMode="SortByTime"
/>
```

Lets say, If the URL of your application is 
http://localhost/SampleApplication, to Check the Trace info for your application change the URL to http://localhost/SampleApplication/trace.axd

**Page Level**

If you are just looking for page level tracing then add the trace attribute to the page directive

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  
Trace="true" 
traceMode="SortByTime"%>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Developers must run profiling to find the performance of their
>   applications

The Visual Studio Profiling Tools let developers measure, evaluate, and target performance-related issues in their code. These tools are fully integrated into the IDE to provide a seamless and approachable user experience.

Profiling an application is straightforward. You begin by creating a new performance session. In Visual Studio Team System Development Edition, you can use the Performance Session Wizard to create a new performance session. After a performance session ends, data gathered during profiling is saved in a .vsp file. You can view the .vsp file inside the IDE. There are several report views available to help visualize and detect performance issues from the data gathered.

[image]

To create and run a performance session find reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)